# Adjusting docker environment for each MLflow model

Tags: docker, pip, mlflow

Imagine a situation, where you have two teams working on some models, for example XGBoost. They
train it and then log the model to common MLflow Tracking Server. One of the teams is using older version,
for example 1.1 and the other team is using newest 1.6 version.

Is it possible to use both of these models to make predictions inside one container,
which downloades the models from MLflow tracking server? Since these two mentioned models
use different versions of XGboost, and the runtime in which they are going to be run has
certain version of the pip packages installed, there is going to be compatibility problem ->
only one model will be able to run in this enviroment without changes. However, both of these models have
requirements.txt file saved as the artifact, and this file specifies the package versions, which the
given model needs. Is it possible to adjust package versions running in the container according to
the currently used model using the requirements.txt artifact file? Or is the only
solution to create two separate docker images, for each of the models and with the
packages that the model needs?

Answer (score 0):

you can make two virtual env inside container (for example conda envs)